# AppHarbor Shared SQL Space Allocation Error

Tags: sql-server-2008, appharbor

We are running the Shared SQL Server Addon under the 'Nano' Plan with 10GB storage.

We are nowhere near approaching our storage limit yet we are intermittently encountering this SQL error when writing to the database:

> Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.*MyTable*' in database
>   '*MyDatabaseId*' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk
>   space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup,
>   adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for
>   existing files in the filegroup.

It seems the problem is because we do not have enough unused space at any given time for the tables we are writing to. Here is the output from `sp_spaceused` on each table:

```
name             rows      reserved    data        index_size   unused
---------------- --------- ----------- ----------- ------------ ------
MyTable1         382862    177608 KB   177536 KB   8 KB         64 KB
---------------- --------- ----------- ----------- ------------ ------
MyTable2         137091    34248 KB    34240 KB    8 KB         0 KB
---------------- --------- ----------- ----------- ------------ ------
```

EDIT: Further inspection shows the physical .mdf file has an Auto-Grow setting of 1024KB, should we expect to see a larger proportion of this as Unused table space?

This is preventing us from creating indexes and worse still causing us to lose data. Is there a way to increase our allocation or another approach to take? Please advise.

Comment: Hi Nick, we had a configuration error on one of the EU instances - if that's where your app is running, then that was probably the problem. It should be resolved now -- sorry about the breakage.

Comment: Can you confirm during which hours or exactly how long this has been a problem for? We are trying to account for our downtime.